# Java and C++ stack implementations with dramatically different performance

Tags: java, c++, performance, comparative-review, stack

I'm developing a small programming language for use in any project I have where I feel a small scripting language could be used well. I've written two emulators for the language, one in C++ and one in Java. The C++ performs faster except for any recursion in the language, in which it suddenly performs terribly!

Here is the code from my language that I am running which runs in 1.5s on the Java emulator and 4s on the C++ emulator:

```
dec i = 0;
recurse();
print i;

def recurse:
    if i < 10000000:
        i++;
        recurse();
    return;
```

This compiles down into the following instructions:

```
% i = 0; #define the alias i as being variable 0;
# i needs to be initialised;
STOREINT i 0;
CALL @recurse; #call the label recurse, push this line onto the stack;
PRINTINTLN $i;
END; #end of program;

@recurse; #define the function recurse;
# if i is < 10000000 then inc i;
GEQ $i 10000000;
JCMP @return; #jump to the return statement
INC i;
CALL @recurse;
@return; 
RETURN; #return back to the line on the top of the stack;
```

The C++ implementation differs slightly from the Java implementation in that it uses an array of unions to store each "typeless" object, whereas Java just uses `Object`. Other than that, the code is almost identical (with C++ not needing to do any casting because from the instructions we can be sure which field  in the union we are using, and therefore we access the correct field instead of casting the `Object` to the correct type in Java. C++ also doesn't need to use `& 0xFF` in order to fix sign problems with the java byte type, as we can make `unsigned char`s). The main difference between them seems to be the performance of the call stacks, which are implemented in each case as follows:

**Java**

```
public class ArrayStack<T> implements Stack<T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Object[] stack;
    protected int capacity;
    protected int pointer;

    public ArrayStack(int capacity)
    {
        stack = new Object[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
        clear();
    }

    public void push(T value)
    {
        stack[pointer++] = value;
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        return (T) stack[--pointer];
    }

    public T peek()
    {
        return (T) stack[pointer-1];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return pointer == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return pointer == capacity;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        pointer = 0;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return pointer;
    }

    public int capacity()
    {
        return capacity;
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
template <class T> class ArrayStack
{
    private:
        T* stack;
        int capacity;
        int pointer;

    public:
        ArrayStack(int capacity)
        {
            this->capacity = capacity;
            stack = new T[capacity];
            clear();
        }

        ~ArrayStack() { delete stack; }
        void push(T value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }
        T pop() { return stack[--pointer]; }
        T peek() const { return stack[pointer-1]; }
        bool isEmpty() const { return pointer == 0; }
        void clear() { pointer = 0; }
        int size() const { return pointer; }
        int getCapacity() { return capacity; }
};
```

I'll provide the case statements running during this program below if anybody wants to see them, but for now I'll leave them out to keep this post a little shorter!

To my eyes, the C++ looks like it should be either faster than or equal to the Java one, as even if new was the slow part of the C++ code, that isn't taken into account in the timing of the program execution, which starts timing as soon as the first instruction is executed. Could it be that I'm storing the stack as a member variable in the Emulator class, and not as a pointer or something like that, or something the JIT compiler can do that the static C++ compiler (on O3) can't?

Comment: **Something the JIT compiler can do that the static C++ compiler (on O3) cant?** -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp12214/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `delete[] stack`? Java stores just references in the stack and C++ stores objects and copies them if needed. This could get pretty slow if `T` is big.

Comment: @maaartinus It should indeed, but the destructor isn't called during the measure of the program runtime either, it is called after the END instruction is executed

Comment: @JaDogg Your comment has lead me to believe the JIT is doing something special here... I ran a similar test after basically converting the above recursive code into an iterative version, and Java completed in 600ms and C++ in 3s. Maybe Java has somehow created compiled code that runs an iteration of those specific instructions or something. Or perhaps it is some other inefficiency in my code. I'll edit my post with more stuff!

Comment: If you make enough `Stack` instances, will you get a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: I believe you will see a remarkable speed up just by using standard containers. Replace `class ArrayStack {};` with `std::vector` and it will be much faster with no work (your implementation of stack is lacking a lot of the normal optimizations). Don't forget to give it a reasonable size by using reserve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Performance

I'll get to a bit of a review, but first, since you're most interested in performance, I've done some benchmarking. In short, all evidence points towards maaartinus' theory being the cause.

### Benchmark.java:

```
public class Benchmark {

    private static class Stored {
        private final int[] big = new int[250];

        public Stored() { }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create the objects up front so we don't include allocation/construction time in the benchmark
        Stored stored[] = new Stored[1000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < stored.length; ++i) { stored[i] = new Stored(); }

        for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();

            ArrayStack<Stored> stack = new ArrayStack<Stored>(1000000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { stack.push(stored[i]); }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { stack.pop(); }

            long end = System.nanoTime();

            if (!stack.isEmpty()) { System.out.println("This is just here to make sure nothing gets optimized out."); }

            System.out.printf("Time: %f seconds%n", (end - start) / 1e9);
        }   
    }
}
```

Once the JVM has warmed up and some JITing has (presumably) happened, each test takes 0.0038 seconds (with a very small variance). If the size of `big` in `Stored` is changed, this doesn't change timings since the stack stuff is still just copying a reference. Even if more references are added to `Stored`, this increasing the size of stored, there is still no time increase. This all makes sense: all Java has to do is copy a pointer, and the size of this pointer is fixed.

### benchmark.cpp

```
int main() {

    // To be consistent with the Java approach, we'll create the objects up front. Noteably, this doesn't actually
    // matter since the copying of the objects is just as expensive as creation.
    // (Note: typically it wouldn't make sense for this to be dynamically allocated, but 1000000 objects was too big for
    // the stack.)
    Stored* stored = new Stored[1000000]();

    // Do the simple approach
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        ArrayStack<Stored> stack(1000000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { stack.push(stored[i]); }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { stack.pop(); }

        if (!stack.isEmpty()) { std::cout << "This is here so the code doesn't get optimized out.\n"; }

        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
        std::cout << "Time: " << diff.count() << " seconds\n";
    }
}
```

This was run with a few different `Stored`s. The first was a relatively large class:

```
struct Stored {
    int x[250];
};
```

The second was a very light class:

```
struct Stored {
    int x[1];
};
```

As a third option, the large class was kept, but rather than storing a value, a pointer was stored in the stack:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { stack.push(&stored[i]); }
```

The timings were 0.30 seconds, 0.001 seconds, and 0.001 seconds for options 1, 2, and 3, repsectively. This is consistent with the Java theory and findings: C++ is peforming expensive copies that Java is not doing.

### Benchmark Conclusions

The question now obviously becomes how to optimize your C++, and unfortunatley there's no simple solution to that without knowing a lot more about what exactly it is that you're putting into your stack. Move semantics are one option, provided your copying is expensive and you'd be happy to sacrifice the object into the stack rather than copy it.

The other option is to move away from value semantics so that copies become cheaper. If you have simple hierarchical ownership semantics (e.g. the objects being stored in the stack will always outlive the stack), this is super easy: just store pointers in the stack instead of objects. If your ownership isn't quite so simple, you would need to consider using something like heap allocation and a smart pointer. Both of these approaches are trade offs though. Smart pointers are safe but relatively expensive to copy, and raw pointers can quickly become a confusing mess if you're not very particular and consistent with your semantics. In both cases you no longer have the pleasantness of value semantics.

Comment: The stacks are actually only given ints, as it represents the line we must jump back to. But your point about expensive copying got me thinking and I have found where the problem is! The programs byte data is stored in a 2d vector and I was writing `std::vector<byte> line = program_memory[program_counter]`. This meant that the line was being copied every time the emulator executed an instruction. Changing it to `std::vector<byte>* = &program_memory[program_counter]` fixed the problem, and resulted in the C++ version being 10 times faster than the Java equivalent. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @J_mie6 Awesome! Glad it got figured out. By the way, you probably want to use a reference instead of a pointer if you can.

Comment: What are the rules of thumb with references vs pointers? I never know quite when to use each in place of the other

Comment: @J_mie6 I'm not really sure, now that I think about it. The only times in which I absolutely always use references over pointers are: 1) Non nullable convenience local variables (`SomeClass& sc = some[super].annoying.way().to[access].it();`), and 2) read only parameters in a function signature (`void f(const T&)` vs `void f(const T*)`). A lot of people (me included) would include a 3rd always: when taking a parameter that might be changed in place (`void f(SomeThing& st) { /* potentially alter st */ }`)

Comment: References are essentially pointers with value semantics except they don't allow null, and they can't mean ownership. What I mean by the ownership is that constructing a class with a pointer is super confusing: `SomeClass(Something* ptr)`. Should SomeClass delete `ptr` in it's constructor? Is it expected to copy it? What in the world does accepting a `Something*` mean? With a reference it's a lot more obvious that either SomeClass must copy it, or that the object referenced must outlive `SomeClass`.

Comment: (If I'm going to continue to drone on a bit, this is actually one of the biggest problems with raw pointers -- there's no enforced ownership semantics. There's just convention and documentation, both of which are open to interpretation and mistake. This is why raw pointers tend to be a very bad idea in modern C++. References don't have this problem because they're more or less a 'safe' subset of pointer.)

Comment: Ok, so when would you absolutely NOT use references?

Comment: @J_mie6 In all honesty, I'm not quite sure. The only thing that immediately jumps to mind is if I wanted something to be able to be NULL.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference) on references and pointers to be useful.

Comment: Quibble: `In both cases, acessing an object through a pointer is slower`. Don't believe that in the sligtest. You are always accessing the object through a pointer (even if it is a local variable). The pointer is just stored in a different register.

Comment: @LokiAstari Oops! Not quite sure what I was thinking there in hindsight. Obviously nothing larger than a register is going to ever be in a register--value or pointer, the same indirection is there. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I don't consider myself a Java expert, but I can certainly comment on some things I see in the C++ implementation that you might want to address.

### Fix the destructor

As has already been noted in the comments, the destructor isn't correct as written.  To match with `new T[capacity]` it should be `delete[] stack`.  That will make it work without crashing, but there are some other issues.

### Understand object creation

In Java, as you know, objects are reference counted and automatically destroyed by the garbage collector when they're no longer needed.  However, in C++, the programmer has both full control and full responsibility over both creation and destruction of the object.  How this affects your `ArrayStack` depends on how it's being used.  One way it might be used is that as each object is created and pushed onto the stack, it's now "owned" by the stack which is therefore responsible for deleting it.  That seems to be the intent because the destructor destroys the objects it contains.

In that case, you need to be explicit about handing over ownership.  Right now, your `push` looks like this:

```
void push(T value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }
```

Because it says `(T value)` instead of using a reference `(T& value)`, it means that it's using pass-by-value.  So even if you call `push` with an already-created `T`, this will make a new one which lives only as long as the function executes.  Then it will use `operator=` to copy that `value` into the `stack`'s version and then destroy the copy.  To make this more concrete, here's an adaptation of a `std::string` class called `MyString`.  Its sole purpose is to demonstrate object creation and deletion:

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString() : str(), id(serial++) { 
        std::cout << "creating empty string " << id << "\n"; }
    MyString(const char *msg) : str(msg), id(serial++) { 
        std::cout << "creating string \"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; }
    MyString(const MyString &s) : str(s.str), id(serial++) { 
        std::cout << "copying string \"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; }
    MyString(MyString &&s) : str(), id(serial++) { 
        std::swap(str, s.str);
        std::cout << "moving string \"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; }
    MyString& operator=(MyString &&s) {
        std::swap(str, s.str);
        std::cout << "moving string via =\"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; 
        return *this; }
    MyString& operator=(MyString &s) {
        str = s.str;
        std::cout << "copying string via =\"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; 
        return *this; }
    ~MyString() { 
        std::cout << "destroying string \"" << str << "\" " 
            << id << "\n"; }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyString &m) {
        return out << m.str;
    }
private:
    static unsigned serial;
    std::string str;
    unsigned id;
};

unsigned MyString::serial = 0;
```

Depending on how you are with C++11 (which this uses), it might not be obvious what this class does.  Simply put, it has four different constructors:  one for no-argument, one to copy from a `const char *`, one to copy from another `Mystring` and a "move constructor" (new in C++11).  [Here is an article](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) that explains Rvalue references and move semantics, so I'll skip all of that for now.  Now let's try it out with your stack:

```
int main()
{
    const int TESTSIZE{3};
    MyString silly{"zoom"};
    ArrayStack<MyString> stack(TESTSIZE);
    for (int i=0; i < TESTSIZE; ++i)
        stack.push(silly);
}
```

When I run this (with the corrected `ArrayStack` destructor), we get this:

```
creating string "zoom" 0
creating empty string 1
creating empty string 2
creating empty string 3
copying string "zoom" 4
copying string via ="zoom" 1
destroying string "zoom" 4
copying string "zoom" 5
copying string via ="zoom" 2
destroying string "zoom" 5
copying string "zoom" 6
copying string via ="zoom" 3
destroying string "zoom" 6
destroying string "zoom" 3
destroying string "zoom" 2
destroying string "zoom" 1
destroying string "zoom" 0
```

As you can see, there is a lot of creating and destroying happening here.  The first one is the creation of `silly` which creates `MyString` instance number 0.  The next three (1, 2 and 3) are due to the `stack = new T[capacity];` line in your constructor.  As explained above, instance 4 is created just for the call to `push` and is destroyed once the `=` operator is complete.  This happens again for the next two instances, which are 5 and 6.  Finally, your destructor gets automatically called at the end of `main` (since `stack` is an automatic variable that is destroyed once it goes out of scope) and finally the original `silly` gets destroyed.  Now that we have some insight, we can see if there are ways to reduce the overhead and therefore speed things up.  I'll describe things step-by-step in the hope that it makes things easier to follow.

### Pass a reference to `push`

The first thing we can do is to pass a reference to `push` instead of forcing the creation of a new object.

```
void push(T &value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }
```

Here's the result of just that change on our instrumented `MyString`:

```
creating string "zoom" 0
creating empty string 1
creating empty string 2
creating empty string 3
copying string via ="zoom" 1
copying string via ="zoom" 2
copying string via ="zoom" 3
destroying string "zoom" 3
destroying string "zoom" 2
destroying string "zoom" 1
destroying string "zoom" 0
```

Much better already, but there's more that can be done.

### Use `const` where practical

As @Corbin noted in a comment, the better signature for the `push` function would be this:

```
void push(const T &value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }
```

By adding the `const` keyword, we make the guarantee that the passed value will not be modified by the function.  Similarly, while the original code has `const` for `size` and `isEmpty`, it should also have the same annotation for `getCapacity`:

```
    int getCapacity() const { return capacity; }
```

### Use a `std::vector` instead of raw pointers

The underlying representation of your stack would likely benefit from being a `std::vector` instead of a stack.  This will solve two problems.  First, there's not much need to allocate a fixed capacity for a `std::vector` but you can specify one if you know it to improve efficiency.  Second, only used values are actually initialized, so rather than constructing useless empty values, you can simply only store useful ones.

### Reconsider the interface

While it makes some sense to want to return a value from `peek` or `pop`, the problem with this approach is that it might not be possible to do so.  In particular, if the stack is empty, what should happen?  One way to handle this would be to `throw` an exception.

### Use smart pointers

Returning to the issue of object ownership, it seems likely that when the stack is created, you don't really want duplicate objects.  If that is the case and you only want one object, you should look into using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if you intend either to not use `std::vector` and keep the current pointer representation, or to use `std::vector` to keep an array of pointers.

### Summary

Although the syntax is quite similar, the way that Java and C++ work can lead to very different things happening with similar looking code, as you have seen.  The key point to remember is that with C++, *you* are responsible for memory management, while in Java, the virtual machine's garbage collection takes care of this for you.  Generally speaking, this gives the edge to C++ for performance because there is no interpretation step required and the generated code is running on the real hardware rather than on a virtual machine requiring additional interpretation.  Being adept in both languages takes time and effort, but is well worth the effort and you're obviously well on your way to that goal.

Comment: +1, however, `void push(T &value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }` should be a const reference.

Comment: @Corbin: yes, I ran out of time yesterday to address that and a few other points.  Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: "In Java, as you know, objects are reference counted" - possibly nitpicking here but that's technically incorrect. There's no reference counting for garbage collection purpose. Instead there's object graph traversal.

Comment: @hawk: Maintaining an object graph is one method of keeping a reference count.  The point is that Java object might be explicitly allocated but is never explicitly freed and is always passed by reference.  I've been reading _Inside the Java 2 Virtual Machine_ lately, but if there's a better information source on this aspect, please let us know.

Comment: For normal operations I don't think C++ has any real advantage over Java. The ability to tune the byte code at runtime is a significant advantage for Java. Java starts breaking down more when you start straining the machine resources if you stay away from that then I would consider both comparable (and if you see a major difference the problem is usually in your code).

Comment: @LokiAstari: When it has been systematically studied, including in [this recent study](https://aisberg.unibg.it/retrieve/handle/10446/27936/10183/gherardi12java.pdf) by Gherardi, Brugali, and Comotti, Java is consistently slower than the corresponding C++ implementation.  Java is getting faster, and in some benchmarks is almost as fast, but C++ still offers a measurable performance advantage over Java.

Comment: @Edward: Yep I used to read the studies all the time. But each one would differ. First C++ is better than Java is better. The difference is always small and also depends on the domain. They are so close its (in my opinion) not worth thinking about the difference (unless you have an application that is running for weeks). The important thing usually comes from the ability of the language to allow the developer to express themselves concisely (as this means shorter development time and easier maintainability). Here C++ wins.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Actually, the studies quite consistently show that C++ is faster.  This also matches my experience.  It is certainly true that for many practical applications, performance doesn't matter much, but the performance difference is still there. Obviously there are more characteristics than raw performance that govern language choice and there is no single "best" language.  But in applications for which performance is important, it's worthwhile knowing the difference.

Comment: Its been a while since I checked. So if you say so I am not going to disagree. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24920543/14065

Comment: FYI, on this machine that Java code (fixed to return early) runs 2.3 times slower than your C++ code in that post.

Answer (score 8):

## Code Review

### Java

Your `peek` and `pop` methods have warning around them due to the unchecked cast. This can be fixed by suppressing the warning on each method, but an easier approach is to store an array of `T` and only do the cast once:

```
public ArrayStack(int capacity)
{
    stack = allocate(capacity);
    this.capacity = capacity;
    clear();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private T[] allocate(int num) {
    return (T[]) new Object[num];
}
```

With this, your `peek` and `pop` no longer need casts and are fully typesafe. You can also do it without a helper method, but it requires an ugly temporary variable:

```
public ArrayStack(int capacity) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] tmpStack = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
    stack = tmpStack;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    clear();
}
```

---

Depending on usecase, it might be worth remembering that your clear() method will retain references to anything stored in the stack, making those objects ineligible for garbage collection. Depending on your object graph and how large the things being stored are, this might mean that an "empty" stack could essentially be holding a lot of memory.

---

`capacity` is superfluous since you can just use `stack.length`. Having an extra variable for something that can be derived very quickly means that you're introducing room for human error ("oh no, I forgot to update capacity correctly somewhere and now the class does crazy things!") for little advantage.

---

You should only bother with a `serialVersionUID` is your class implements `Serializable`.

---

`pointer` is a slightly confusing name. Maybe `position` instead?

### C++

#### Bugs and errors

Your class has incorrect copy and assignment handling. Right now either operation would result in a double free and likely cause a crash once the second object was destructed.

This can be remedied by following the rule of three (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but the real solution is to avoid unnecessary manual memory management (sometimes called the rule of 0). In this case, you can use a `std::vector`. As long as you make sure to size the vector up front (e.g. `std::vector<T> v(capacity)`), it should have the same performance as a bare array.

---

As mentioned in the comments, `delete stack;` should be `delete[] stack;` since it was allocated with `new[]`.

---

I'm a bit wary of a custom, non-growing stack. I have a suspicion you should just be using `std::stack`. Best case, you preallocate enough space that it never grows. Worst case, it grows a bit and you avoid a segfault. Seems like a win-win either way.

---

Your `pop` implementation is not exception safe. In fact, it's actually impossible in C++ to have an exception safe `pop` that returns a value. What happens if the copying (or moving if you take the above suggestion) throws an exception? `pointer` has already been decremented, so suddenly you have no way to attempt to get at that object again once the exception has been handled.

This is actually the reason `pop` in the standard library doesn't return and there's instead a `top` method.

---

Your constuctor should be explicit. Otherwise super weird things like `f(ArrayStack) {} void g() { f(5); }` are valid.

---

`getCapacity()` should be `const`.

#### Miscellaneous

`push` should either take `value` by a const-reference.

```
// This brings the timings of the first case down from .30 seconds to .20 seconds
void push(const T& value) { stack[pointer++] = value; }
```

If you're using C++11 features, you should also provide a move option:

```
void push(T&& value) { stack[pointer++] = std::forward<T>(value); }
```

Your `pop` should also use move semantics if you're using C++11: `void pop() { return std::move(stack[--pointer]); }`

---

Peek should return a const reference. Let the consumer decide if he wants to copy before you do it for him.

#### Style

`pointer` is very confusing on the C++ side since I expect it to be a pointer.

---

To be consistent with the C++ standard library, `isEmpty` should be `empty()`, `getCapacity()` should be `capacity()`, and `peek()` should be `top()`.

---

#### Summary

All in all, a cleaned up version might look like this:

```
template <class T> class ArrayStack
{
    private:
        std::vector<T> elements;

    public:
        explicit ArrayStack(int capacity)
        {
            elements.reserve(capacity);
        }

        void push(const T& value) { elements.push_back(value); }
        void push(T&& value) { elements.push_back(std::forward<T>(value)); }

        void pop() { elements.pop_back(); }

        T& top() { return elements.back(); }
        const T& top() const { return elements.back(); }

        bool empty() const { return elements.empty(); }

        void clear() { elements.clear(); }

        int size() const { return elements.size(); }

        int capacity() const { return elements.capacity(); }
};
```

Note that as a side effect of `std::vector`, this has not only some bug files and simplifications, it also has a few happy side effects:

- Pushing when full will now result in the vector growing instead of a segfault.
- Popping now destructs the item stored in the stack immediately instead of upon stack destruction. For classes that are small value wise but hold on to a lot of data, this can be very meaningful.

All in all, this cleaned up version really just brings home that you should use `std::stack`. Containers are surprisingly hard to get right in C++, and they often offer more functionality (sometimes in subtle ways) than your own implementation is ever going to have.

Comment: By the way, in the Java my Stack interface is indeed Serializable, which is why it has the id. As for the `T[]` cast, I'm surprised I didn't notice that! Isn't it sufficient to do; `stack = (T[]) new Object[capacity];` instead of a method or a temporary variable? Thanks for the info on why my pop is bad and telling me about explicit, I didn't even know that was a thing :) I will switch over to the std::stack, I'm just used to creating containers in Java quite a bit now for more specialised or faster implementations of their defaults, ie why I have the ArrayStack in the Java in the first place.

Comment: @J_mie6 You can't put a \@SuppressWarnings annotation on an assignment to an existing variable. It has to be done on a variable declaration + assignment. Just a weird limitation in Java, unfortunately :/.

Comment: It can be done on the method overall though: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayStack(int capacity)
    {
        stack = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
        clear();
    }`, at least, eclipse isn't complaining

Comment: @J_mie6 Right, but then you risk suppressing a warning that shouldn't have been suppressed. For example, if you added another line 3 months from now with something in it that's wrong and would generate a warning, it would be erroneously suppressed.